# How to display comma delimited list in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file written :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href ="movies.xslt"?>
<movies>
  <movie>
    <id>01</id>
    <title>Die Hard</title>
    <Principaldirector>John McTiernan</Principaldirector>
    <year>1988</year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <genre>Suspense</genre>
    <uri>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095016/?ref_=nv_sr_1</uri>
  </movie>
```

And I need to display the genre in a single cell of a table as a comma-delimited list. Like

> Action, Suspense

I have this XSLT code, which just grabs the first genre with a comma, but not the other ones.

```
    <xsl:template match="movie">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xsl:for-each` here...

```
<td>
   <xsl:for-each select="genre">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>        
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Just wanted to ask if you can explain what the value:of statement does? I am not understanding the period within the select element.

Comment: The period symbol represents the current node. As the code now does `<xsl:for-each select="genre">` that means you are now positioned on the `genre` element, so if you were then to do `<xsl:value-of select="genre"/>` it would look for an element called `genre` that was a child of the current `genre` element, which obviously doesn't exist. So use `.` to get the string value of the node of your current context.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It really helped to understand the concept.